# jaxws-maven-plugin or jaxb2-maven-plugin to create java classes from WSDL

Tags: java, maven

I am developing a web service contract-first. I have seen a lot of developers use the plugin `jaxws-maven-plugin`in the pom.xml to create java classes from the wsdl file (or the xsd file), while other developers use some pluggin variation of `jaxb2-maven-plugin` to do it.

Does someone know advantage of using one or the other?. Is any of them obsolete?

Answer (score 0):

jaxb2 - maven - plugin is a maven plugin that replaces XJC and schemagen to complete the transformation of Java classes and schema files.
When using jaxb2: schemagen generates a schema file, it cannot be generated if the Java bean property name is different from the specified name

Jaxws-maven-plugin generates the Web Service client Java code.

Most of the time Jaxws-maven -plugin is more recommended for use

Comment: Hi Jay. Do you know if Jaxws-maven-plugin could be used only for client java code?. I have read than it can be used in server java code if you change the property `genJWS` by true.

Comment: "it cannot be generated if the Java bean property name is different from the specified name" - what does it mean? property name different from the name of what?